# Technology/Hardware that can detect contents of warehouse goods

Tags: hardware, inventory, warehouse

Is there any technology/hardware that can detect the contents of warehouse goods? This will be used to resolve the problem with pilferage without the need of checking the items per box manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broad question.  However, you are probably looking for Barcode, Barcode scanners, or RFID technology.